# read SOAP request in node.js

Tags: xml, node.js, express, soap, soap-client

How do you read the actual xml content of a SOAP request? `req.body` appears to be empty. The only information I see is `req.headers.soapaction`, which gives me some url.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.headers.soapaction); // this gives some url
    console.log(req.body); // but nothing here.. how can i see the xml content?
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my answer is correct, but I was able to get my data (which was XML content).  Here's my solution:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
...

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.text({type:'text/*'})); // reads the body as text (see Express 4 API docs)

...

app.get((req,resp) => {
    var body = req.body; // Should be a giant object of characters
    var data = JSON.stringify(body); // Put all the characters into a single string
    console.log("Data: " + data);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App running on ${PORT}`));
```

Hope this helps!